# Send mass emails in php in sections? Stop spam?

Tags: php, email, spam, massmail

So, I am running on a a free webhost 3owl.com. I know that free hosts suck compared to paid but its temporary. Anyways, I have 90 users that need email sent to them.

The issue:

```
I cannot send them at a speed of more than 1 every 4 seconds.

I must not run the while loop for more than 40 seconds at a time.
```

So, I need help figuring out how to send the email in sections.

```
Send email 1
4 second break
Send email 2
4 second break
Send email 3
4 second break
Send email 4
4 second break
Send email 5
4 second break
Send email 6
4 second break
Send email 7
4 second break
Send email 8
4 second break
Send email 9
4 second break
Send email 10
---------------
STOP SCRIPT in a way that doesnt load the website? for 10 seconds
---------------
continue with the next 10
```

Is this even possible?
Maybe some sort of checkbox system which list the users and you can check who you wish to email it to...

Here is my current code

```
mail_users($_POST['subject'], $_POST['content']);
```

And the function for that looks like this:

```
function mail_users($subject, $body) {
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT `email`, `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1");
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
        email($row['email'], $subject, "Hello ". $row['first_name'] . ",\n\n" . $body);
        sleep(4);
    }
}
```

I am in great need of help. Maybe some javascript is needed for the checkboxes

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to do this using code in a web page? Have you considered exporting your email list to Outlook or ConstantContact?

Comment: Do you have shell access? Replace sendmail with qmail and you can queue your sending. its worked for me in the same situation where I must regulate the number of messages sent in a time interval. And not to advertise, but Digital Ocean offers darn fine lampp hosting for $5 a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the way I did it (for a long time with a website that had thousands of users)

This is totally a hack, but it works.

Build a page that sends a single email and mark that user as "sent" in the db, eg (sent=1)

Select the next user that is not "sent" (eg sent=0)

Put a meta refresh tag to refresh every minute on the page , open a browser, launch the page and let it run for an hour and a half or even all night...

In the am, clear the db of (set all users sent=0)

(I used to have my scripts run all night... )

Comment: A code example please...

Comment: Ok, [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh]  '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">'

Comment: Within the head tag (this is in classic asp because that's what the site was written in - told you it was a long time ago) `<META http-equiv=refresh content="<%

if request("wait")<>"" then
 response.write request("wait")
else
 response.write "600"
end if

select case request("wf")
 case "newsletter"
%>;URL=http://www.mydomain.com//newsletter_autosend.asp?test=<%=request("test")%>&resend=<%=request("resend")%>&newsid=<%=request("newsid")%>">`

Comment: I have no idea why this question is off-topic or my solution is downvoted. This is a common coding problem - an entrepreneur with few resources needs a way to write code the fits within the constraints of his budget. I had the exact same problem building LandAndFarm.com.  I was on a limited hosting service with a free business model and I found a solution that worked great. I sent a single email on a page and then waited and reloaded the page. The page was password protected so only I could access it. I really did send tens of thousands of newsletters this way for a while.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use JavaScript and use Ajax to call the PHP that sends the mail. Use a setTimeOut to call the script every four seconds and keep track of which email is being sent through query string variables.